# How do CSRF attacks work if all browsers use the Same-Origin Policy?

Tags: javascript, security, csrf, same-origin-policy

One thing I can't wrap my head around with CSRF attacks is how an attack can lure us to a different site and still be able to use our session data.

I thought that if the browser is pointed to a website like "trustworthysite.com" then all requests(forms, ajax, xmlhttprequests, etc) would have to be to the same domain

eg.

```
<form action="http://trustworthysite.com/login" method="POST">
    Your name: <input type="text"><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10000">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="evil_hacker">
</form>
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://trustworthysite.com/post",
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

But if the attacker lured use to "malicioussite.com" and then tried to run the Javascript code above wouldn't it fail because it is a "cross-orgin" request?

How could it still work?

Comment: [OWASP: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: The Same-Origin Policy applies only to reading data, not writing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy stops JavaScript from *reading* the response from a different origin. It doesn't stop the *request* being made (except under some limited circumstances).

CSRF attacks are primarily about sending malicious instructions, not about stealing data.

Comment: Thx! Great answer!